# Error initializing the debugger: Mono.Debugging.Soft.DisconnectedException

Tags: xamarin.android

After upgrading to version 4.0.4, I started getting the connection with the debugger has been lost error. I've tried to re-install all the components (monodevelop, android sdk, java sdk, etc.). I also cleaned up the registry, rebooted after re-installation. But all the effort did not make any difference. All the android os versions (1.6 to 4.0) targeted all had the same error when debugging. Previous version worked most of the time during debugging. It was quite difficult to find answers on the Xamarin web site. If someone can shed light on this issue, I'd very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I fix the same issue by going to
Mono android options and setting :

- linking: adk and user assemblies
- Use shared runtime: yes
- use fastdeployment: yes

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything rebooting etc.and found this thread during my frustration. At last I tried to build in release mode instead of debug and that magically solved the issue and attached the debugger. There after I could switch back to debug without any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Visual studio after deleting the .vs,bin and obj folders

Comment: wow this actually worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this as well.

I upgraded to 4.05 beta, but the problem persisted.   Then I disabled the Project `Properties -> Mono Android Options -> Use Fast Deployment` (debug mode only), selected Deploy Solution manually, and the debugger magically attached and worked correctly.

Not sure if the 4.05 upgrade was needed, but I suspect turning off Fast Deployment was what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs each time we change a file: for example when you change main.axml file. or when add a new .so file. just run your project twice (first this error appears and for the second turn it run normally)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem trying to debug an Android application on Visual Studio 2022, the difficulty was caused by a code I was running on the MainPage right after the InitializeComponent() call.
SOLUTION: Removed the code and it worked
ABOUT THE CODE: the code was suppose to bring an string, by my mistake the string was empty.

```
public MainPage(){
   InitializeComponent();
   // The code was here, I removed it, and it worked.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- I solved this issue by downloading [Mono.Posix.dll][1] and paste it
  to path mention in exception. My path : C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio
- [1]https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/attachment.cgi?id=22522

  Plus add the following lines in devenev.exe.config at path C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE:

```html
   
   <runtime>
       <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/> </runtime>
```

Comment: My VS 2017 was died after this

Answer (score -2):

Run the App in Release mode in not in debug it will work