# Deployment and USB device issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am using my physical Android device to do the deployment of my project. After I moved the folder to a new location in my computer, I am since unable to select(or even view) my device from the emulator list.

Now I try to run the app on the emulator, which after building gives this error:
[image]

It also gives a red line under this piece of code:

```
public App()
{
      **InitializeComponent();**

      MainPage = new LoginSystem.MainPage();
}
```

The "Quick Actions" tool tells me that - "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context."

If I remove the initialize component line, I am able to build and deploy my project. However, i really need that line of code. How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

After following the link suggested by PiLHA - [getting an error on InitializeComponent() on xaml.cs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927536/getting-an-error-on-initializecomponent-on-xaml-cs-files?rq=1)

I am able to build the project and deploy it, however, i get a new error:
[image]

And I am still not able to get the USB connected device to show up in the emulator's list.

I am assuming that there is a problem with the debugger, that is causing the error and not showing the USB device. I have researched quite a bit, yet no solid solution. Please help.

**UPDATE 2**

I have set my device to allow for debugging. I had been using this device for this purpose before, it's just that this is a new obstacle is am facing at the moment.
[image]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927536/getting-an-error-on-initializecomponent-on-xaml-cs-files?rq=1

Comment: I looked at that link- it fixed my red line under 'InitializeComponent', however i still see the same build error: "There were deployment error. Continue?"

Comment: Does the error occur in the same place? What is the new error? Have you tried giving a clean in the project/solution and make a new build? On window dialog click yes and see the error.

Comment: I have updated the status in the question.

Comment: Searching a little I found some possible solutions: Try clearing all your break points OR install VS Update 3 OR check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504760/error-initializing-the-debugger-mono-debugging-soft-disconnectedexception

Comment: is your device still set up to debug over usb in the 'developer options' section.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Yes it is.

Comment: @PiLHA Alright, let me try doing all the suggested steps you gave me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only reason I've ever seen the device not show in visual studio is when thres been an issue with it getting registered as a debuggable device, so that's quite strange.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt indeed buuuut, changing project settings or move folfers is always painful especially when you have many references

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Please check Update 2, i did configure the phone to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where even after enabling USB debugging, my physical device wouldn't show up in the list. Here is the solution I found:

1. Open storage settings.
2. Click on the three dots on the right side and select *USB computer connection*.
3. Uncheck and check the mass storage option.

Your device should now show up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

For the USB Debug device - it turns out that i just had to "repair" my Visual Studio 2017.

As for the Error:

> mono.debugging.soft.connectionexception

I literally created a new project and transferred my folders there. This was the only solution i could come up with, took me hours but now it's done.